# conditional with value from a particular cell in excel

Tags: python, pandas, matlab

I am trying to write a following matlab code in python:

```
function[x,y,z] = Testfunc(filename, newdata, a, b)
sheetname = 'Test1';
data = xlsread(filename, sheetname);
if data(1) == 1
    newdata(1,3) = data(2);
    newdata(1,4) = data(3);
    newdata(1,5) = data(4);
    newdata(1,6) = data(5)
else
....
....
....
```

It is very long function but this is the part where I am stuck and have no clue at all.
This is what I have written so far in python:

```
import pandas as pd
def test_func(filepath, newdata, a, b):
    data = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name = 'Test1')
    if data[0] == 1:
```

I am stuck here guys and I am also even not sure if the 'if' statement is right or not. I am looking for suggestions and help.

Info: excel sheet has 1 row and 13 columns, newdata is also a 2-D Matrix

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? Why did you stop writing the code? Go ahead and complete it and then check for errors/mistakes.

Comment: I have no clue how to write the next line, if I get a little bit of help then I would complete the code on my own

Answer (score 2):

Try running that code and printing out your dataframe (`print(data)`). You will see that a dataframe is different than a MATLAB matrix. `read_excel` will try to infer your columns, so you will probably have no rows and just columns. To prevent pandas from reading the column use:

```
data = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name='Test1', header=None)
```

Accessing `data` using an index will index that row. So your comparison is trying to find if the row is equal to 1 (which is never true in your case). To index a given cell, you must first index the row. To achieve what you are doing in MATLAB, use the `iloc` indexer on your dataframe: `data.iloc[0,0]`. What this does in accesses row 0, element 0. Your code should look like this:

```
import pandas as pd
def test_func(filepath, newdata, a, b):
    data = pd.read_excel(filepath, sheet_name = 'Test1')
    if data.iloc[0,0] == 1:
        newdata.iloc[0,2:6] = data.iloc[0,1:5]
        ....
```

I suggest you read up on [indexing in pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: Thanks Kevin, that helped me a lot